# vim - open stdin and files in split windows

Tags: command-line, vim

Is it possible to open vim with stdin in one window, and a file in another?

`vim -` starts vim with text from stdin in the buffer

`vim -o file1 file2` starts vim with files in multiple split windows

Can they be combined? `vim -o file1 -` doesn't work; it dies with a `Too many edit arguments` error. I know I can use `vim -` and then `:split file1`, but I'd like to do it with command-line flags if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you cannot use `-o`, you can execute any commands passed with `-c`:

```
$ vim - -c 'split file1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out another cool way to open from multiple temporary files (without reading from stdin, though):

`vim -O <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` (split)

`vim -p <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` (tabbed)

Of course you can execute any command within the brackets:

`vim -O <(cat file1) <(cat file2)`

(Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the synopsis of vim's man page, the answer is no. You may specify multiple files, or a hyphen, but not both:

```
NAME
       vim - Vi IMproved, a programmer's text editor

SYNOPSIS
       vim [options] [file ..]
       vim [options] -
       vim [options] -t tag
       vim [options] -q [errorfile]
```

One way you may be able to accomplish your goal is using command substitution with file input redirection:

```
vim -o mine.txt yours.txt <(diff mine.txt yours.txt)
```

The above command opens three windows in vim:

1. Regular file: mine.txt
2. Regular file: yours.txt
3. Diff the two files, then redirect the output of diff as file input to vim.

The output of `<(any command here)` is essentially considered by vim to be just another file to be opened.